# How can i end a loop by myself?

Tags: python, loops

I am learning Python. I am trying to create a program that will calculate my final score in college.  My question is if I can end an `if` loop by myself?
E.g. I want my program to repeat the question **"Do you want to add a grade?"** as long as the question is **"yes"**, and as soon as the answer is **no**, I want my program to leave this part of my code.

What is the easiest way to do this?

```
noten = [] #list for grades
lp = []    #list for the weight of my different grades
p_antwort = ['y', 'yes'] #p_antwort = positive answer
n_antwort = ['n', 'no']  #n_antwort = negative answer

txt = input("Do you want to add a grade? y/n ")
if txt in p_antwort:
   i = input("What grade did you get? ")
   noten.extend(i)
   txt_2 = input("Do you want to add another one? y/n")
   if txt_2 in p_antwort:
        i = input("What grade did you get? ")
        noten.extend(i)
```

Comment: Generally this is achieved by the `while` operator in lots of languages. Check here: https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`while`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) loop to keep grabbing grades until the user types in a key to exit the loop such as `quit`.

```
grades = [] 

txt = input("What grade did you get? Enter 'quit' to exit: ")
while txt != 'quit':
    grades.append(txt)
    txt = input("What grade did you get? Enter 'quit' to exit: ")

print(grades)
```

Example interaction

> What grade did you get? Enter 'quit' to exit: A
>
> What grade did you get? Enter 'quit' to exit: B
>
> What grade did you get? Enter 'quit' to exit: C
>
> What grade did you get? Enter 'quit' to exit: D
>
> What grade did you get? Enter 'quit' to exit: quit
>
> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while` loop, with a `done` variable, then update `done` on each iteration of the loop, by checking if the user is interested in adding another entry.

For example:

```py
done = False

while not done:
    # do stuff
    done = input("Want to add another? (y/n)") == "n"
```

Or you can use a `keep_going` variable and do basically the opposite of the above code.

Comment: A variation: `while True:
  if input('Do you want to add a grade? y/n ') != 'y': break
`

Answer (score 0):

The  way you could do it is with the while loop.

First you need to instanciate the variable text for the while loop

```
text = ""
text = input("Do you want to add a grade? y/n ")
while text != "n":
   if txt in p_antwort:
      # do some stuff
   text = input("Do you want to add a grade? y/n ")
```

I think this should work